# In Voiceover Iphone ,after selecting suggestions focus is not shifting to input combobox

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, accessibility, voiceover

Even though we are shifting the focus to input through the javascript code, the focus is going somewhere else instead of going to the input.

Same issue is observed in w3 aria combobox as well as in link https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-autocomplete-none.html

Expected behaviour:
In voiceover,Focus should move to the input after selecting any suggestion from the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

The current version of this pattern is here, and it seems to work a little better: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/combobox/combobox-autocomplete-list.html

Otherwise, these are mostly illustrations on how something could work. The code is not meant to be put in production environments as is.